# Multiple image in one post but all in one container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been stuck in a logic in one of my projects I am working on. This is not WordPress post. I want to display multiple images may be 1,2,3.... up to 10 in a same div container, which will be uploaded from the backend system. This should be displayed in one view similar to the screen shot below.

[image]

I have tried to arrange the images in a div container without JavaScript. I am new to jQuery and finding it difficult without a clue to proceed.

[Codepen sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPBPwR) `here`

I know it should possible using jQuery only.

If you need more clarification please comment I will update my question.

**

> Note: Facebook post have the multiple Image upload in one view I'm trying the same Output.

**

Comment: what do you mean by "one view"? make an image in image editor so that it is clear what you want. And yes upload your code here.

Comment: Please see my edited description

Comment: @Preveen Kumar, Your Proud should worth anything...Useless...?

Comment: @KarthiKeyan What I would say you is, you must still clarify more on your question. Do you agree? Well, I have been working on JavaScript and jQuery till these years, but still I am unable to understand your question, even after a lot of talking with you. Is this my fault, if so, I am sorry!

Comment: IMHO, reputation is very worth, but please, do not waste it. That's all I would like to say.

Comment: Solution is more worth even reputation...  Don't comment out of topic SOF is not a place to chat...

Answer (score 10):

I guess you might be looking for [jQuery.Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin. This will arrange the images based on:

1. Number of images.
2. Screen resolution.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.grid').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: 200
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.0/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://shechive.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/cute-cartoons-21.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/ac/bb/d4/acbbd49b22b8c556979418f6618a35fd.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://hdwallpaper1080.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/178714_cartoon-jerry-tom-wallpaper-cartoons-wallpapers_1920x1080.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://shechive.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/cute-cartoons-21.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/ac/bb/d4/acbbd49b22b8c556979418f6618a35fd.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://hdwallpaper1080.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/178714_cartoon-jerry-tom-wallpaper-cartoons-wallpapers_1920x1080.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://shechive.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/cute-cartoons-21.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/ac/bb/d4/acbbd49b22b8c556979418f6618a35fd.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://hdwallpaper1080.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/178714_cartoon-jerry-tom-wallpaper-cartoons-wallpapers_1920x1080.jpg"/></div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Please read clearly before answer, i know the masonry, isotope .. but my requirement is different.. this is CMS img posting not possible to add code here...

Comment: what about the post detail on the right?, and CMS client can add image in there own post that time not possible to add <div class="grid-item">

Comment: OKay... What kind of CMS are you using da?

Comment: Hmm... Yikes... *gives up*

Comment: Arranging Images of an unknown size and number needs an algorithm, so you always end up with a jQuery plugin – even CSS flexbox solutions provide no help here. jQuery plugins are just code based on jQuery, so if you can run custom jQuery code, you can at least paste the plugin source in your script. A lightweight solution for masonry would be [Freetile](https://alternativeto.net/software/freetile) or [Salvattore](http://salvattore.com). If you're running your images through a PHP framework, you should at least have the option to preprocess them in a simple way, like a adding cropping container

Comment: @KarthiKeyan Laravel framework  ísnt cms ... its framework like symfony

Comment: We customize it to CMS

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
.post-img {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  max-height: 400px;
  -moz-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-gap: 3%;
    -moz-column-width: 30%;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 3%;
    -webkit-column-width: 30%;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 3%;
    column-width: 30%;
}
```

to stack them vertically (pinterest style), css only, as demonstrated here by some guy: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/7Chkz/ Or try using this plugin for a different type of layout: http://masonry.desandro.com/

**EDIT**
http://jsfiddle.net/ffkdurw9/ here you can see a js to alternate the column numbers based on your predifined style preferences. I assume 1 img full size, 2 images half size 3 or more you go for 3 columns

**EDIT 2** css columns layout does not work with ie8, but since even Microsoft isn't supporting it anymore...you should ask for a ton of money to do that yourself :))

**EDIT 3** the js provided in the fiddle above will not work properly if there are multiple elements of this format. You will need to find an equivalent to jQuery.each() or use jQuery to handle that.

Comment: Thanks, But Is it provide dynamic solution? that means 1, 2, 3, ...images. it's possible to post any number of image here.

Comment: not really no, you must assume an initial number of children. What you could do is use javascript to detect the number of children in your post-img, then pass a class based on how many columns you need (1 for 1 child, 2 for 2 children or 3 for 3 or more children I suppose). I'll update my answer with how that might look like

Comment: @KarthiKeyan I added a jsfiddle example of how you could use js to change between 3 predefined styles for the column layout

Answer (score 0):

should use `width` and `height` in `img tag` (For `Fix`)

Example

```
.post-img { 
   float: left;
   width: 40%;
   max-height: 400px;
   background-color: red; //custom
   padding: 10px; // custom
   margin: 10px; // custom  
 }

.post-img img {
  max-width: 100px; // custom
  max-height: 100px; // custom
}
```

Comment: did you see the facebook post image upload? i need that kind of output.. in my side i'm working on that kind of output.. thanks

Comment: yeah I see it. you will need **jquery** to select and custom @KarthiKeyan :P

Answer (score -1):

Use `float` for each image.

```css
#image-container img{
  float:left; 
  max-width:33.33%
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but try to under stand my requirement. and post a valuable things